# Failing to understand django get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have this model:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, unique=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        'Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("book_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

And this view:

```
class BookDetail(DetailView):
    model = Book
```

It will connect me to the template as well called (`book_detail.html`).

My question is, do I need to also specify in the app's `urls.py` the url path in this case?

```
    path('book/<int:pk>/',views.BookDetail.as_view(),name='book_detail')
```

I thought that if I used `get_absolute_url(self)` I wouldn't need to do that but I am finding some resources where it says it is [necessary](https://ngangasn.com/what-is-get_absolute_url-in-django/).
I find it confusing since to me it feels like duplicating the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, do I need to also specify in the app's urls.py the url path in this case?

**Yes**, the `get_absolute_url` does *not* create a URL entry.

The [**`.get_absolute_url()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) is a method that can be put on a model class (or any class if you want). Django is not very interested in it when it *inspects* the model, so that does not matter.

There are basically two use-cases where this is useful: when redirecting to a model object, and in templates.

Indeed, when you use [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) you can pass a model object where the model has a `.get_absolute_url()` method. In that case, it will call `.get_absolute_url()` and return a `HttpResponseRedirect` to that path. This is also useful in some class-based views, like a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) or an [**`UpdateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) redirect when the creation or update was successful. You can specify a `success_url` or `get_success_url` to specify to where the view should redirect. But if you do not specify this, and the model has a `.get_absolute_url()` method, it will redirect to the result of the `.get_absolute_url()` of the created or updated object. Which is a popular use case: if you wrote a blog article, a sensical thing to do is after it is created, to redirect to the page of that article.

Another use-cases is using this in the template, where it prevents constructing the path manually, or with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url). So one can link to a blog post with:

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post }}</a>
```

It is thus only a simple function that determines an absolute path to a *canonical* view, to show that blog article, profile, or something similar. It has no triggers attached to it to create views or paths.

> I thought that if I used `get_absolute_url(self)` I wouldn't need to do that but I am finding some resources where it says it is necessary. I find it confusing since to me it feels like duplicating the code.

**No**, you simply say where one can find a canonical view of that object, so a method that will determine the URL to see a blog article. But it does not say much about the structure of the path. That logic happens in the URL. Likely it would be a bad idea to look for `get_absolute_url`s and make url patterns based on that: it would mean the paths are "hidden" in the models, so a developer might overlook these and it would thus be less transparent what these views would do, and to what view function or class-based view these would point.